# Resizing NSWindow don't autoresize its contentView correctly

Tags: swift, macos-sierra

I have an `NSWindow` with it's contentView. In the `awakeFromNib()` of the `NSWindow` I have the following code:

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
  super.awakeFromNib()
  /// Customize Window through XIBs
    self.title = "Main Window"
    let screenFrame = NSScreen.main?.frame
    let windowPercentage: CGFloat = 0.9;
    let offset: CGFloat = (1.0 - windowPercentage) / 2.0;
    let windowFrame: NSRect = NSRect(x: (screenFrame?.width)! * offset, y: (screenFrame?.height)! * offset, width: (screenFrame?.width)! * windowPercentage, height: (screenFrame?.height)! * windowPercentage )
    self.setFrame(windowFrame,display: true,animate: true)
    self.backgroundColor = NSColor.lightGray
    self.isRestorable = true


  // Customize contentView
    let viewPercentage: CGFloat = 0.6
    self.contentView?.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: self.frame.size.width * viewPercentage, height: self.frame.size.height))
    self.contentView?.setFrameOrigin( NSMakePoint( ( (self.frame.width) - (self.contentView?.frame.width)! )/2, ( (self.frame.height) - (self.contentView?.frame.height)!)/2) )
    self.contentView?.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height, .minXMargin,.maxXMargin,.maxYMargin,.minYMargin]
}
```

I am trying to set up the `contentView` in the center and with a percentage of its `NSWindow` frame but it's failing when i resize the window. As soon as I start to resize the Window the `contentView` it's not resizing correctly, as you can see from the following image(the second one):

Image one

[image]

Image two

[image]

Should I override the `resize(withOldSuperviewSize:)` method to achieve this? (also the autoresize from interface builder don't resolve the issue)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't attempt to change the size of the content view like that. I don't believe it's supported. The window controls the content view's size.

If you want a view of your own to occupy only a portion of the window's content area, you should add your view as a subview of the content view.

Comment: I did as you suggested and now it's working. So basically i should use the 'contentView' to manipulate the view hierarchy and not as a custom View. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can set the `contentView` to a custom view and that's well supported. It's just attempting to control its size which is a problem.

Comment: Usually i create a custom view because i need to manipulate its size, so I don't know a good use case to set my custom view as the `contentview`.